# How to force bootstrap 3 to load a view regardless of device size detected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Bootstrap 3 does not support BlackBerry devices, menus won't work, links are broken. I have several sites done using bootstrap 3 and need a solution.

I would like to be able to force bootstrap to use the small[tablet] or medium[desktop] views when a Blackberry device is detected.

Is there a way that this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you may want use the black art of user agent sniffing. Check for a Blackberry browser, and then use media queries to achieve what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to solve your problem. When detecting a BlackBerry device you can create new media queries for resolutions larger than 992px to constrain the width of the .container element to the width of 750px for example (from media query up to 768px) - always assuming that you are using default bootstrap classes.